# How to compose json responses from two different controllers? Spring 3/Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring

Currently I have two controllers that return a domain model in JSON format
Is it possible when the first controller is called, inside the handler method, to get JSON response from the second controller, and attach it to the JSON response of the first one

Answer (score 0):

There is not any direct way to combine object of two different controllers. If you want to combine these objects. Create a method that perform action to generate required object in different class. Now when you required json object from second controller then call it from second controller and use it in json object. And when you required it from first controller then call this custom method and combine it with object of first controller and use it as json object.